# How can I debug Camunda webapps in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, web-applications, camunda

I want to debug Camunda webapps in Eclipse.

How do I set this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my solution I used the Camunda Tomcat distribution. For other Application Servers, the steps might vary.

### Requirements:

- Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers

### Steps

- Create a new server in your workspace

  - Select an Apache Tomcat 7 server (new -> other -> Server, Server type Apache Tomcat 7.0.
  - Select the server installation directory of the Camunda BPM platform (e.g., `\camunda-bpm-tomcat-7.1.0-Final\server\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\`)
- Copy the Camunda-specific config files (located in the `\conf` folder of your distro, e.g., `\camunda-bpm-tomcat-7.1.0-Final\server\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\conf\`) to the server directory

  - server.xml
  - bpm-platform.xml
- Add the webapp as a Maven project with dependency to camunda-webapp-tomcat

  - Content of pom.xml:

    `<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
       http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.camunda.consulting</groupId>
      <artifactId>debugging-webapp</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.webapp</groupId>
          <artifactId>camunda-webapp-tomcat</artifactId>
          <version>7.1.0-Final</version>
          <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>camunda-bpm-nexus</id>
          <name>camunda-bpm-nexus</name>
          <url>https://app.camunda.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </project>`
- Deploy this webapp to the server by hitting "Run as -> "Run on Server"

  - Choose the above configured server
  - If necessary, adjust the mapping of the web module
- Start the server in debugging mode
- Open the webapp in your browser

Answer (score 0):

1. [Create a new Maven Project in Eclipse](http://docs.camunda.org/latest/guides/getting-started-guides/spring-framework/#set-up/eclipse)
2. [Add the camunda & Spring framework dependencies](http://docs.camunda.org/latest/guides/getting-started-guides/spring-framework/#set-up/maven)
3. [Add the web.xml file for bootstrapping the Spring container](http://docs.camunda.org/latest/guides/getting-started-guides/spring-framework/#set-up/web.xml)
4. [Add a Spring application context XML configuration file](http://docs.camunda.org/latest/guides/getting-started-guides/spring-framework/#set-up/application-context)

If you dont know how to install maven in eclipse. Just download spring framework**strong text**

Comment: Thanks for your help hurricane. I've added the solution I found myself as well.